# Update iPhone 3GS from iOS 3.1.3

Tags: iphone, ios

How to update my iPhone 3GS from iOS 3.1.3?

Comment: @Red The iPhone 3Gs has a lower case 's'.

Answer (score 2):

Connect the iPhone to iTunes, select it in the top left, and then click Update.